# Taylor Remainder formula for $\sin(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

The general formula for remainder of Taylor polynomial is:
$$R_n(x)=\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(c)$$
where $c$ is an unknown point between $a$ and $x$.

For $\cos(x)$ the book I am reading says :

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\cos(c)$$

But I don't understand why last term has $\cos(c)$. In fact $(n+1)$th derivative of $\sin(x)$ at $x=c$ can be either of $\pm\sin c$,$\pm\cos c$.  but why it considered only $\cos c$ among these four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin x$. Then observe that $f^{(n)}(x) = \sin {(x + n\pi /2)}$. So
$ f^{(2n+1)}(x) = \sin {(x + \frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2})} $.
Then it can be easily observed that $f^{(2n+1)}(x) = (-1)^n \cos x$ since $ \sin {(x + \frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2}}){}{}{} = \cos x \sin ({(2n+1)\pi /2}) = (-1)^n \cos x$

Comment: Shouldn't we place $n+1$th derivative of $f$ in the equation? ($f^{(n+1)}$)

Comment: You can consider that you are evaluating power series till $m = 2n$ by so remainder term at $m = 2n +1$ is evaluated. Note that $2n ^{th}$ differential of $ \sin x$ is $0$ at $x = 0$

Comment: To find $f^{(2n+1)}(x)$we could also find $f'(x)$ , $f'''(x)$,... to recognize the pattern $\cos x,-\cos x,\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ :

Taylor-Lagrange's theorem states that, for any $ a,x\in\mathbb{R} $, we have : $$ \sin{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{\frac{\sin^{\left(k\right)}\left(0\right)}{k!}x^{k}}+R_{2n}\left(x\right) $$

Where $ R_{2n}\left(x\right) $ can be witten as follows $$ R_{2n}\left(x\right)=\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\sin^{\left(2n+1\right)}\left(\xi_{x}\right) $$ for some $ \xi_{x}\in\left(a,x\right) $.

Since, for any $ \left(n,x\right)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{R} $, $ \sin^{\left(2n\right)}\left(x\right)=\left(-1\right)^{n}\sin{x} $, and $ \sin^{\left(2n+1\right)}\left(x\right)=\left(-1\right)^{n}\cos{x} $, we have the following : $$ \sin{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}x^{2k+1}}+\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\cos{\xi_{x}} $$